# Как создать несколько primary key или другим способом разрешить ссылаться другим таблицам на данное поле?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

У меня есть база данных

```
CREATE TABLE themes
(
    id        SERIAL            NOT NULL,
    them_name VARCHAR(255)      NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id, them_name)
); 


CREATE TABLE rules
(
    id          SERIAL        NOT NULL,
    them        INTEGER,
    rule_body   TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(them) REFERENCES themes(id)
);


CREATE TABLE dictionary
(
    id          SERIAL    NOT NULL,
    word        TEXT      NOT NULL,
    translation TEXT      NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id, word)
);


CREATE TABLE verbs
(
    id           SERIAL           NOT NULL,
    first_form   VARCHAR(50)      NOT NULL,
    seckond_form VARCHAR(50),
    third_form   VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY(id, first_form)
);


CREATE TABLE users
(
    id         SERIAL          NOT NULL,
    chat_id    BIGINT          NOT NULL,
    username   VARCHAR(255),
    full_name  VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(id, chat_id)
);


CREATE TABLE students
(
    id           SERIAL  NOT NULL,
    user_id      INTEGER NOT NULL,
    teacher      INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(teacher) REFERENCES teachers(id)

);


CREATE TABLE teachers
(
    id      SERIAL  NOT NULL,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
);


CREATE TABLE word_student
(
    id         SERIAL   NOT NULL,
    dict_id    INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    student_id INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(dict_id)    REFERENCES dictionary(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(student_id) REFERENCES students(id)
);
```

Я пытаюсь создать ее с помощью скрипта, но у меня не получается, выводится ошибка

> asyncpg.exceptions.InvalidForeignKeyError: there is no unique
> constraint matching given keys for referenced table "themes"

Насколько я знаю, в sql есть возможность создавать prymary key для 2 и более полей внутри таблицы, я это сделал `PRIMARY KEY(id, them_name), но при создании базы, выводится ошибка, что на id невозможно сослаться, т.к он не является первичным ключом. В чем ошибка, как мне сделать несколько первичных ключей, или разрешить ссылаться на поля другими способами ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно повторить колонки в основной таблице и дочерней, не забывая что группы колонок должны повторятся в обеих таблицах.

```
FOREIGN KEY(them,them_name) REFERENCES themes(id, them_name)
```

подробнее [тут](https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/foreign-key-constraint.php#:%7E:text=A%20FOREIGN%20KEY%20constraint%20contains,key%20values%20from%20another%20table.)

> The point to be remembered that, type and number of columns in FOREIGN
> KEY must be matched with the type and number of columns with the
> referenced columns in referenced table.

Comment: А можно ли присвоить ключ, по которому можно будет сослаться, но чтоб он не был превичным?

Comment: А смысл? при любом раскладе будет первичный где то на него и ссылайтесь. Зачем ссылаться на ссылку

Comment: @DenverToha есть просто key

Comment: @eri, а как его использовать, при попытке KEY(название поля) выдает ошибку